# Typo3 tx_news: How to show only category of user config in backend module

Tags: categories, typo3-7.6.x, tx-news

I have tx_news system with many categories and every backend user should have control for only one category.  In the user settings I can set his category... 
But in the backend module the user still sees all categories!
Is it possible to show a user only news of "his" category?

My System:
Typo3: 7.6.12,
tx_news: 5.2.0

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Check out the latest version, IMO I fixed that!

Comment: Hi Georg
Thanks for your feedback!
I updated to 5.3.1 out of TER but still have the same problem!
User of Cat1 sees still Cat1 and Cat2 news and can edit both categories...
I also tried activating in setting: records.categoryBeGroupTceFormsRestriction 
but think this something else... ?